# Simulating binomial distributions in R

Tags: r, distribution, inference

I am attempting to simulate a binomial distribution T~B(10, p) in R with p being 
p ~U(0,1).

I created the following piece of code:

```
 Bin_sim<-function(n) {
Prob<- sample(0:10, size = n, replace=T)
Prob2<-rbinom(n=n, size=10, prob=(Prob/10))
Prob3<-Prob[Prob2==8]

table(Prob3) / length(Prob3)
}
```

The following code produces this result:

```
 Bin_sim(10000)
Prob3
          3           4           5           6           7           8 
0.001322751 0.009259259 0.039682540 0.141534392 0.268518519 0.320105820 
          9 
0.219576720
```

Am I heading in the right direction at all if I for example want to simulate the distribution of all successful probabilities where T=8?
Help would be useful, thanks in advance.

Comment: No. For starters you aren't actually simulating a uniform distribution.  Do you need to simulate this? I think the answer can be derived analytically.

Comment: Your `p` are not being chosen according to `U(0,1)`. Instead you seem to have a discrete distribution which takes on 11 possible values (0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0). Is there any reason that you are not using `runif()`?

Comment: As @Dason suggested, you don't need a simulation. Because a uniform distribution is a special case of a beta distribution and beta distributions are conjugate priors to binomial, the distribution of `p` given that `T = 8` is also a beta distribution. Furthermore, the parameters are easy to work out.